# Mass convert HH:MM:SS to seconds and update

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in my database that I need to convert a varchar field (it's in HH:NN:SS format) to seconds and do this for all the rows in the table. Right now, this is how the table looks:

```
Select *
from timeResponse


ID      Unit  Time   Seconds
-----------------------------
F6161   a1    4:01     null
F6161   a2    3:45     null
F6162   v1    30:50    null
F6163   d3    1:30:04  null
......
```

When the conversion update is done, it should look like:

```
 ID      Unit  Time   Seconds
-----------------------------
F6161    a1    4:01     241
F6161    a2    3:45     225
F6162    v1    30:50    1850
F6163    d3    1:30:04  5404
......
```

This is just an example. The total number of rows is over 60000, so this will be a mass update, which I have not done before.

So far, I haven't even figured out how to convert the HH:MM:SS to seconds...

Comment: What's wrong with a simple `Hour * 3600 + Minute * 60 + Second`?

Comment: Your question says `HH::NN:SS` i.e. 2 colons, your sample data says `1;30:04` i.e. a semi-colon. Can you ensure your question is 100% clear and correct please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit] After futher examination it appears the implicit conversion doesn't work for all of the sample data provided.  The code below parses the varchar times into components and multiplies.

```
drop table if exists strings;
go
create table strings(time_str   varchar(30));

insert strings(time_str) values
('4:01'),
('3:45'),
('30:50'),
('1:30:45')

select t_split.l2+t_split.m2*60+t_split.f2*3600 Seconds
from strings s
     cross apply 
     (select isnull(cast(substring(s.time_str, len(s.time_str)-1, 2) as int), 0) l2,
             isnull(cast(substring(s.time_str, len(s.time_str)-4, 2) as int), 0) m2,
             isnull(cast(substring(s.time_str, len(s.time_str)-7, 2) as int), 0) f2) t_split;
```

Update statement

```
update s
set Seconds=(t_split.l2+t_split.m2*60+t_split.f2*3600)
from strings s
     cross apply
      (select isnull(cast(substring(s.time_str, len(s.time_str)-1, 2) as int), 0) l2,
              isnull(cast(substring(s.time_str, len(s.time_str)-4, 2) as int), 0) m2,
              isnull(cast(substring(s.time_str, len(s.time_str)-7, 2) as int), 0) f2) t_split;
```

Results

```
Seconds
241
225
1850
5445
```

Comment: Thanks! That is working perfectly for converting to seconds. Now I need to figure out how to update each row with the seconds.

Comment: Added the update statement